# pandas assign with new column name as string

Tags: python, pandas

I recently discovered pandas ["assign" method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) which I find very elegant.
My issue is that the name of the new column is assigned as keyword, so it cannot have spaces or dashes in it.

```
df = DataFrame({'A': range(1, 11), 'B': np.random.randn(10)})
df.assign(ln_A=lambda x: np.log(x.A))
        A         B      ln_A
0   1  0.426905  0.000000
1   2 -0.780949  0.693147
2   3 -0.418711  1.098612
3   4 -0.269708  1.386294
4   5 -0.274002  1.609438
5   6 -0.500792  1.791759
6   7  1.649697  1.945910
7   8 -1.495604  2.079442
8   9  0.549296  2.197225
9  10 -0.758542  2.302585
```

but what if I want to name the new column "ln(A)" for example?
E.g.

```
df.assign(ln(A) = lambda x: np.log(x.A))
df.assign("ln(A)" = lambda x: np.log(x.A))


File "<ipython-input-7-de0da86dce68>", line 1
df.assign(ln(A) = lambda x: np.log(x.A))
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I know I could rename the column right after the .assign call, but I want to understand more about this method and its syntax.

Comment: well the parentheses immediately treat this as some kind of method call which is an illegal name for a var: https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: From the example above, I can still do df['log(A)'] = df.sum(axis = 1), but I understand why I get the error above (it was somewhat expected)

Comment: but `df['log(A)'] ` is a `str` for which the variable name rules don't apply

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can pass the keyword arguments to `assign` as a dictionary, like so:

```
kwargs = {"ln(A)" : lambda x: np.log(x.A)}
df.assign(**kwargs)

    A         B     ln(A)
0   1  0.500033  0.000000
1   2 -0.392229  0.693147
2   3  0.385512  1.098612
3   4 -0.029816  1.386294
4   5 -2.386748  1.609438
5   6 -1.828487  1.791759
6   7  0.096117  1.945910
7   8 -2.867469  2.079442
8   9 -0.731787  2.197225
9  10 -0.686110  2.302585
```

Comment: You can also do it in a single line with `df.assign(**{"ln(A)" : lambda x: np.log(x.A)})`

Answer (score 9):

`assign` expects a bunch of key word arguments.  It will, in turn, assign columns with the names of the key words.  That's handy, but you can't pass an expression as the key word.  This is spelled out by @EdChum in the comments with this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

use `insert` instead for inplace transformation

```
df.insert(2, 'ln(A)', np.log(df.A))
df
```

[image]

---

use `concat` if you don't want inplace

```
pd.concat([df, np.log(df.A).rename('log(A)')], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
There is a difference in behavior as insert only acts inplace